# Relationship Details within the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking at writing a query that will take the `cat_id` and check if there is a `parent_id`. If there is, return the `cat_name` of the `parent_id`.

Here is an example of the table:

[image]

I have attempted to use a nested query, but I don't think this is even close.

```
SELECT cat_name
FROM exp_categories
WHERE parent_id = (SELECT parent_id 
                   FROM exp_categories
                   WHERE cat_id = '2'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

SECOND ATTEMPT:

```
SELECT cat2.cat_name
                             FROM exp_categories AS cat1
                             LEFT JOIN exp_categories AS cat2 ON cat1.cat_id = cat2.parent_id
                             WHERE cat1.cat_id = 2
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` back to the same table.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you! I didn't think of this. I have added a 'SECOND ATTEMPT' to my question. Is this along the right lines? Still not outputing the parents category name yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.cat_name
FROM exp_categories A
JOIN exp_categories B ON A.parent_id = B.cat_id
WHERE A.cat_id=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` can slove your issue.

```
SELECT cat2.cat_name
FROM exp_categories AS cat1
INNER JOIN exp_categories AS cat2 ON cat1.cat_id = cat2.parent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the subselect using an inner join with the same table (self join) and filter the second table to cat_id = 2

```
  SELECT A.cat_name
  FROM exp_categories A
  JOIN exp_categories B ON A.parent_id = B.cat_id 
          and b.cat_id=2;
```